# JavaScript doesn't throw error

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I am confused about JS behavior, actualy develop large app in CoffeScript, Este-library, Google-closure and React. For sure I can share more info or code, if no idea comes.

This "non-throwing" behavior start, when component (goog.ui.Component) can't by decorate, call not exist func in React or if I simple remove Google Analytic init code -> variable window['ga'] not exist but window['ga'].someFunc() not throw any error. Here is not 1:1 code.

```
Component = function() { }
Component.prototype.match_ = null;
Component.prototype.show = function() {
    'use strict';
    console.log(this.match_);
    this.match_.functionDoesntExist();
}
```

Process code like this:

```
var component = new Component();
component.show();
```

make output like this:

```
null
```

If I replace "Component.prototype.show":

```
// ...
Component.prototype.show = function() {
    'use strict';
    try {
        console.log(this.match_);
        this.match_.functionDoesntExist();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error detected!", error);
    }
}
```

It will trigger error and show correctly:

```
"Error detected! TypeError: Cannot read property 'functionDoesntExist' of null(…)"
```

Here is Google Analytic example, code is 1:1.

```
goog.provide('core.Analytics');
goog.require('goog.Uri');

/**
  @constructor
 */
core.Analytics = function() {
  this.ga_ = window['ga'];
  return;
}
goog.addSingletonGetter(core.Analytics);

/**
  @private
 */
core.Analytics.prototype.ga_ = null;

/**
  @public
 */
core.Analytics.prototype.sendPageView = function() {
  var page;
  page = this.getCurrentPage_();
  this.ga_('send', {
    'page': page
  });
};

/**
  @private
  @return {string}
 */
core.Analytics.prototype.getCurrentPage_ = function() {
  var page, uri;
  uri = new goog.Uri(window['location']['href']);
  page = uri.getPath();
  if (uri.hasQuery()) {
    page += '?' + uri.getQuery();
  }
  if (uri.hasFragment()) {
    page += '#' + uri.getFragment();
  }
  return page;
};
```

and in some other file:

```
goog.require('core.Analytics');

core.Analytics.getInstance().sendPageView();
```

PS: sorry for bad en (:

Comment: Do you really have `'use sctrict'` in your code? It's "strict", not "sctrict".

Comment: @Juhana thanks for correct. I have 'use strict' in code.